# Rails fragment caching not working locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added the following at the top of my index.html.haml:

```
- cache do

  content
```

And as far as I can see, the content is not cached. My server output shows that when I reload the page, it still fetches all the info from the database again.

I haven't tried on live as I don't want to push anything before it's 100% working. What am I doing wrong? Am I not understanding how it's supposed to work? I've set the `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cache_store configures which cache store to use for Rails caching so you need to specify that

You need to set cache store in general config.

```
config.cache_store = xyz,abc       # PUT THIS
```

**Options that you can set:**

```
 :memory_store, :file_store, :mem_cache_store
```